Data Import Handler for Solr 9.6.1
What are the external plugins or packages for data import handler in solr v9.6.1? And how do I install those?
I added a plugin from github (https://github.com/SearchScale/dataimporthandler) but this is not working. I am getting

Version incompatible! Solr version: 9.6.1, package version constraint: 9.4.0

for all version in data-import-handler. I followed these steps : https://github.com/SearchScale/dataimporthandler.

The library will have to be updated and built to support the new version. You'll have to ask the maintainers about that project to do that. https://github.com/SearchScale/dataimporthandler/blob/b813ab794ef5f67f94eccfbd212b3c1764232ae3/repo/repository.json#L262
